# I'm trying to make part of the link visible on hover but its pushing both up and down at the same time. How can i prevent from pushing on hover

Tags: html, css

**I only want to push dots down on hover not the main content**

```css
.links {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 70px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 180px;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out all;
}

a {
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out all;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover .learnMore {
  display: block;
}

/* *this is the hidden part* */
.learnMore {
  display: none;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out all;
}

/* **__this part needs to be pushed down on hover __** */
.dots {
  color: rgb(30, 140, 184);
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  font-family: soleil, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

/*>I dont wanna use opacity**/
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="">Digital Marketing <div class="learnMore">Learn More</div><div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Security Solutions<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Healthcare Technology<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Business Process Automation<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>

</div>
```

*Only dots needs to be pushed down not the text above it *

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the `height` property for a tag.

```
a {
  height:100px;  /* add this line */
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out all;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
.links {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 70px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 180px;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out all;
}

a {
  height:100px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out all;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover .learnMore {
  display: block;
}

/* *this is the hidden part* */
.learnMore {
  display: none;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out all;
}

/* **__this part needs to be pushed down on hover __** */
.dots {
  color: rgb(30, 140, 184);
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  font-family: soleil, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

/*>I dont wanna use opacity**/
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="">Digital Marketing <div class="learnMore">Learn More</div><div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Security Solutions<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Healthcare Technology<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>
  <a href="">Business Process Automation<div class="learnMore">Learn More</div> <div class="dots">...</div></a>

</div>
```